# Sharepoint 2007 issue: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint(SP) Custom Webservice which i have deployed in Machine A,B and Machine C. Machine A is SharePoint 2007 and Machine B is SharePoint 2010 and Machine C is another SharePoint 2007.

I have installed My Application in Machine D, From this Application i am running Services which does the crawling of all the documents of Machine A,MachineB and Machine C one at a time. For crawling of documents of all the 3 machines, SP Custom Webservice is required which i have deployed in ISAPI folder respectively in all these 3 machines.

Crawling is happing fine in Machine B and Machine C. But i am getting the below error for Machine A,

> Error:  CiteCheck.SharePointConnector.SharePointConnectorService -
>   ThreadId=[8]-Exception occurred during connector run: message=[The
>   request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.], stacktrace=[   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)
>
> at
>   CiteCheck.SharePointServices.SPExtendedService.ExtendedService.GetListItemPermissions(String
>   siteURL)

Please some one help me out in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I it using AD to authenticate? Perhaps there is a difference in users from one machine to another?

Comment: Not very sure where I need to provide the accesses to the local sharepoint user but we have compared a lot to these machines but no luck :(.

Comment: Any idea? Kindly provide some pointers.

Comment: Hi, I am still searching for this issues. What I found is that sharepoint sites were '0' in the case of SP 2007 but there were 3 in the case of SP 2010. Due to Zero (0) cites, further steps were restricted. Any idea from this?